# Beginner angularjs - including directive within directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is probably as basic as it gets. I have some simple markup that's suppose to represent a list:

```
<unordered-list>
    <list-item></list-item>
    <list-item></list-item>
</unordered-list>
```

I also have two directives defined for `unordered-list` and `list-item`:

```
.directive('unorderedList', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<ul></ul>'
    };
})
.directive('listItem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<li>Test</li>'
    }
});
```

Yet when I run this (http://jsfiddle.net/esWUD/), the only thing rendered is the `<ul>`. No `<li>Test</li>` elements render within the `<ul>`.

Why not don't they render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use [ngTransclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) to allow directives to have sub-elements. Set `transclude: true` in `unorderedList`.

```
    transclude: true,
    template: '<ul ng-transclude></ul>'
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pp86m/).

Comment: I tried `transclude: true` without `ng-transclude` in the template and it didn't work. Does one always have to include `ng-transclude` in the template when they've already specified `transclude: true`?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know. It can be bothersome, but gives greater control: you can have more complex templates, with a `<div ng-transclude></div>` somewhere in the template. I would personally love to see it working as we both initially expected.